# How many ways to divide $n$ different pieces of chocolate in two non empty groups?

Tags: combinatorics

After the example I think that the order of the groups doesn't matter so ${(A),(B,C)}$ and $(B,C),(A)$ counted as $1$.

Suppose we split $5$ chocolates into a group of size $1$ and a group of size of $4$. So there are $5$ different ways.

Next split the numbers into a group of size $2$ and a group of size $3$. Using the binomial coefficient I get $10$ ways to do this.

So all together for $n=5$ I found $15$ ways.

I've started to calculate the $n$ for "little" numbers just like, $1,2,3,4,5$ and I got the assumption that the formula is $2^{n-1}-1$.

Is that true? And how can I show that my assumption is correct?

Comment: *we split 5 chocolates into a group of size 1 and a group of size of 4*, first one is $5$, second one is $\binom 84$. use Stars and Bars.

Comment: So... you have $2^n$ distinct subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ -- calling a subset $S$, you then have $2^n$ distinct pairs $(S, S^c)$. Since order does not matter, this gives you $2^{n-1}$ ways to divide into two sets $\{ S, S^c \}$. To that, you should remove one possibility -- the empty set/full set pair $\{\emptyset, \{1,\dots,n\}\}$. This will give you $2^{n-1}-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to consider putting some/all/none of the chocolates on the left and the rest on the right.  Each chocolate can go either way, so there are $2^n$ possibilities.

But $2$ of these possibilities leave one side empty.  Ignoring these, there are $2^n-2$ possibilities.

Each pattern has a distinct reflection, swapping all those on the left with all those on the right.  If you regard reflections as equivalent patterns, then there are $\frac{2^n-2}{2} = 2^{n-1}-1$ possibilities.